# To read two elements of lists

Tags: python, list

I have this code

def ch1(div, pares):
    for j in zip(div,pares):
        dtm=pares[j]
        etiqueta=div[j]

```
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=dfm['Date'],
                        open=dfm['Open'],
                        high=dfm['High'],
                        low=dfm['Low'],
                        close=dfm['Price'])])


    fig.update_layout(
        title= etiqueta,
    )

    fig.show()
```

Comment: what is `divisas` ?

Comment: What about `pares[0]` ?

Comment: What is the `READ` method that you call?

Comment: I have putting the new code without this error

Comment: So what is the `READ` function you call ? Did you implement it ?

Comment: Now, I have the code over these comments

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be found here:
[How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Your code should look like something similar to this:

```
def ch1(div, pares):
    for m_div, m_pares in zip(div, pares):
        dtm=m_pares
        etiqueta=m_div                

        fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=dfm['Date'],
                            open=dfm['Open'],
                            high=dfm['High'],
                            low=dfm['Low'],
                            close=dfm['Price'])])


        fig.update_layout(
            title= etiqueta,
        )

        fig.show()

ch1(div, pares)
```

Comment: With this, I have this error TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Comment: This is wrong!
j is a tuple and list can't indexed by tuple.

Comment: what Do I can?  so that in my graphs (list 1 items), my n tags appear (list 2 items)

Comment: @Davk and what can I do then? How can I put the list 1 label in the chart of list 2... each label on its chart... the lists are sorted

Comment: @PedroPuertas, i've corrected the usage of the zip function